# soma de valores com ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Boa noite

Estou tendo um problema de somar valores com ng-repeat

#### object 1

```
COMISSAO_CORRETOR: "5.0"
CPF_CONTRATO: "xxx.xxx.xxx-xx"
NUMERO_CONTRATO: "1234567"
VALOR_BRUTO: "70000.00"
VALOR_COMISSAO: "3500.00"
VALOR_LIQUIDO: "70000.00"
```

#### object 2

```
COMISSAO_CORRETOR: "5.0"
CPF_CONTRATO: "xxx-xxx-xxx-xx"
NUMERO_CONTRATO: "98765442"
VALOR_BRUTO: "10000.00"
VALOR_COMISSAO: "500.00"
VALOR_LIQUIDO: "10000.00"
```

Estou querendo somar o `VALO_COMISSAO` e estou usando a seguinte `function`

#### FUNCTION

```
$scope.GetTotal = function () {
  var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.relatorios.length; i++){
        var relatorio = $scope.relatorios[i];
        total += (relatorio.VALOR_COMISSAO);
    }
    return total;

}
```

Mas o total está sendo retornado assim `03500.00500.00`

Comment: E se você retira-se as aspas duplas do atributo valor comissão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converta sua String (relatorio.VALOR_COMISSAO) para Float, logo que seu atributo está em string ele está concatenando os valores.

```
$scope.GetTotal = function () {
  var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.relatorios.length; i++){
        var relatorio = $scope.relatorios[i];
        total += parseFloat(relatorio.VALOR_COMISSAO);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Retire as aspas duplas do atributo valor comissão, funcionou? AngularJS, assim como outros frameworks e o JavaScript, reconhecem as aspas duplas como uma String e não um valor númerico para realizar operações matemáticas.

Ou utilize `parseFloat` caso o valor é sempre recebido como String e entre aspas duplas.